# EF Core, Service and Repository patterns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

Just to learn about patterns I'm creating my Web API with these projects:
Entities, Repositories, Service and the API application.

Each controller in APIs use dependency injection to his corresponding service; each service use DI to multiple repositories; Repositories are used to get data  from the DbContext and Entities contains DbContext and the DbSets.

As example let's say that when I call the /teams/1 endpoint:

- the `GetTeam(id)` function in controller call `_teamService.GetTeam(id);`
- the service call `_teamRepository.GetTeam(id);`
- the repository does a LINQ call to `Context.Team.First(...)` a give back to the service the Team entity model;
- the service get the model and map it to a DTO that go back to the controller;
- the controller give it to the application in JSON format.

Is this a right way to manage the flow?

In addition, imagine that the controller must retrieve the team and all its competitions: is it right to inject the CompetitionRepository and use it from the TeamService? Something like:

TeamService.cs

```
return new DTOObject {
    team = _teamRepo.GetTeam(id),
    competitions = _compRepo.GetCompsByTeam(id) <-- is a list
}
```

Comment: Your question will surely be closed because it is subjective but this is the only example of properly implemented repository pattern over EF I have seen on the web - https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

However please consider NOT using repository pattern and using the data context directly in your service layer. It will make your life much easier and the value of the repository pattern is pretty much 0 for 99% of the projects.

Comment: The DbContext _is_ your repository.  You can add convenience methods and interfaces to it, which is better than wrapping it behind lots of additional repositories.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Nope. DbContext is Unit of Work. DbSet is a repository. However DbSet is a repository only in the sense of EF. It doesn't help much if you want to use another data access technology. The main goal of a repository is to be able to change the data access but the EF implementation only allows you to change it with another EF implementation. If you want to change your DataAccess to stored procedures good luck doing that with the DbSets. A real repository will allow that without changes to the service layer

Comment: My point was that if you want a repository type that is easy to provide multiple implementations of you can accomplish that with interfaces implemented by your DbContext.  And there's a _fundamental_ tradeoff in using a Repository that doesn't expose an IQueryable<T> property for each entity, as it forces you to specify queries in the wrong component.

Comment: I agree with both of your comments, I wish Microsoft would be more explicit in this. The repository pattern is only useful if you may be changing your data access. If you don't want to change ORMs then don't use it. It's not a horrible nightmare but it just doesn't add anything. Plenty of people still use it but only because they're used to using it in other stacks or because people told them to. It's pretty silly and Microsoft should clearly say this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer to return entities from my services and not DTOs. The reason is that sometimes the result of a service call is used to create an ASP.NET MVC View Model and sometimes a DTO to return as a JSON. Sometimes the requirements for these DTOs are different, the server side ViewModels can see things that should not be exposed to the client. You can make a DTO in your service layer but in most cases it is just another mapping that you have to take care of for not that much value. This is why I create DTOs or ViewModels directly from entities in the controller.

Also the repository pattern is mostly useless. It might be useful if you change your data store but in practice these kinds of changes come with a lot of other changes to the business logic so most of your service layer is rewritten anyway so the value is lost.

Comment: In the years since I gave that answer I've changed my mind and now prever to return DTOs from my service layer. The repository pattern is still useless